# Multiple collectionViews in single TableCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am planning to take multiple collectionView inside single tableView Cell.

What I really want is to show album photos in this manner (UI is important). See image:

[image]

how can make this UI ?

Till now I have take a TableView -> TableCell (Single) -> 3 different collectionView inside cell.

Code:

**CustomGalleryController**

```
class CustomGalleryController: UIViewController {

    var arrayOfPHAsset = [PHAsset]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        CustomAlbum().fetchCustomAlbumPhotos { (array) in
            self.arrayOfPHAsset = array
            CustomGalleryTableCell().firstCollectionArray  = array
            CustomGalleryTableCell().secondCollectionArray = array
            CustomGalleryTableCell().thirdCollectionArray  = array
            //self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }



    }

extension CustomGalleryController : UITableViewDelegate{

}

extension CustomGalleryController : UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomGalleryTableCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomGalleryTableCell

        return cell
    }
}
```

**CustomGalleryTableCell**

```
class CustomGalleryTableCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet var firstCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var secondCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var thirdCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var firstCollectionArray = [PHAsset]()
    var secondCollectionArray = [PHAsset]()
    var thirdCollectionArray = [PHAsset]()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}

extension CustomGalleryTableCell : UICollectionViewDataSource{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//        if collectionView == firstCollectionView {
//            return 1;//firstCollectionArray.count
//        }else if collectionView == secondCollectionView {
//            return 1;//secondCollectionArray.count
//        }else{
//            return 1;//thirdCollectionArray.count
//        }
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView == firstCollectionView {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FirstCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! FirstCollectionCell

            return cell
        }else if collectionView == secondCollectionView {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SecondCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! SecondCollectionCell

            return cell
        }else{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ThirdCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! ThirdCollectionCell

            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

But getting crash:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException',
>   reason: '-[UITableView collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1049ed600

`po 0x1049ed600` gives:

> ```
> <UITableView: 0x1049ed600; frame = (0 0; 414 736); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17424b550>;
> ```
>
> layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize:
>   {414, 44}>

1. Please suggest any other and good way to achieve this UI?
2. What may be the cause of crash if my way of making this UI is correct?

Comment: try collection view custom layouts https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Answer (score 1):

This would achievable using the **[CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout)** made by [chiahsien](https://github.com/chiahsien). I already used this library and I must say it works really great.

You can install it using pods:

```
pod 'CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout/Swift'
```

The Demo in Swift can be found **[here](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout/tree/develop/Demo)**.

The only thing different from this example is that you have a certain padding on each column on the top, but I'm sure this is achievable also.

Comment: It depends the image size ? in this library?

Comment: Yes, but it works the without issues if the image size is always the same.

Comment: yeah thats the problem here like those 3 columns are same if you scroll vertically. its not random

Comment: If the cell size of each column is the same, then you'll get the exact UI like in the image. You just set the initial top padding in each column and you're good to go.

Comment: can you please tell exactly how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

> Please suggest any other and good way to achieve this UI?

If you are aiming to achieve what are you mentioning the in screenshot, there is no need to implement it as a tableview which contains collectionviews, instead, the straightforward way to work with [*UICollectionViewLayout*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout).

As a tip, for the purpose of saving some time and effort, you could find a library that can do the job for you, such as:

- [CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout).

Or if you are interested in reordering the items:

- [RAReorderableLayout](https://github.com/ra1028/RAReorderableLayout).

Comment: but how to achieve the top padding for particular column in CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout ?

Comment: If I got it right, there are 2 properties for what are you asking for:  `minimumColumnSpacing` and `minimumInteritemSpacing`

Comment: No, like top padding you can see for every column is different.

Comment: Well, as a workaround you could let the height of the cell itself to be larger than the imageView and then controlling the `y` of the origin of the imageView...

Comment: can you please tell exactly how to do it ?

Comment: I assume that it would be broad to do the whole thing; I would suggest to play around it by yourself and if you got a problem you should post a question about it.

Answer (score 0):

Beginner with swift and Xcode here. I've been looking for a solution to populate two CollectionView in a single TableViewCell. Even though this might not exactly be appropriate for your case, the title of your question matches :-) Finally managed to do it by using the tag attribute in the storyboard.

Here's how I did it:

- First give a tag number to each CollectionView in the storyboard
- In your ViewControllerDataSource, check if it's the right CollectionView by using an if statement and return whatever's needed (numberOfItemsInSection, cellForItemAt).

  ```
  extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          if collectionView.tag == 0 {
              return imageArray1.count
          } else {
              return imageArray2.count
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Hope this helps!